# Javascript firing canvas changing dimension

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a possibility to fire when a canvas element dimension is changed?
I tried but doesn't work.

```
canvas.addEventListener( 'resize', function canvasResize (){
console.log("hello");
}, false );
```

Comment: When is the canvas dimension changing? Is it upon browser window resizing? On user click?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

But your canvas doesn't change size on its own. Usually it's tied (through style) to the size of the window, which means you can do

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', (function canvasResize (){
    // handle as if canvas was resized
    // the canvas is this in the callback
}).bind(canvas), false );
```

Comment: The problem is that canvas dimension changes without changing window dimension

Comment: How so ? If it's not the window, it's trough one of your actions, and so it's easy. In any case you don't have many alternatives apart using `setInterval` to check the size which is a terrible practice.